# Does there exist a practical application of calling a program with neither instruction data nor a list of accounts?

Tags: instructions

Each [instruction](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/transactions#instructions) in a transaction can include:

- The address of a program to invoke
- A list of accounts the program can access during its execution
- A byte buffer of instruction data

Can you give an example of a practical application – in use today – of an instruction that invokes a program by address, but has neither a list of accounts, nor instruction data?

Answer (score 3):

Your program could log 10Kb of data every time it's invoked, preventing public explorers from showing execution logs about the remaining CPIs.

Example:
Program `DpqbTera2sSAjwjJewqrXof5hzUzMdKUd4hsUvgxEMm8` does this, but has ix data, but theoretically not necessary. [Example explorer link](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/fNBhmKhc8h4pyjS7sY5Goc61Z3D9MYtJ429ErxTwV8W1grXjrrTE4jcymvfWQ513VxntnVQEibi4QScPEAmQJZp)

Comment: Fascinating ‘practical’ application!

Answer (score 1):

The `get_minimum_delegation` instruction in the stake program is another example, but it isn't currently active on mainnet. It does take instruction data, however.

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/f2f1dab5ea7ac66757b85e88ddd5cc9846e5640c/sdk/program/src/stake/instruction.rs#L256